# Qt Unit Test not working on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, qt, unit-testing

I get the following messages while try to run my Qt Unit Test on Linux Mint system:
"expected ')' before 'Util'
File not found command-line"
Already reinstalled and updated my Qt and nothing, the test runs without problems on Windows, but i need it to run on Linux.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When posting questions you should provide all the details to reproduce your problem. Please reed How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm guessing that your code is missing some include statement.